# How to use a JQuery progress bar with dynamically assigned input IDs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, progress-bar

Part of a table created in an MVC View:

[image: Table]

Some of the HTML behind it:

```
...
<tr>
    <td>
        <div id="implG13">252,849.00</div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div id="progressBarG13"></div></td>
    <td>
        <div id="unimplG13">234,687.00</div>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>
        <div id="implG19">239,773.00</div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div id="progressBarG19"></div></td>
    <td>
        <div id="unimplG19">174,397.00</div>
    </td>
</tr>
...
```

I want to be able to display a `Progress Bar` on each row of the table, between these two columns, that graphically represents the percentage of 'cost savings' that have been implemented.

i.e. for the first row the JQuery might be something like:

```
function CalculatePercentage(){
    return ($("#implG13").val() / ($("#implG13").val() + $("#unimplG13").val()));
}

$("#progressbarG13").progressbar({
    $value : CalculatePercentage()
});
```

The problem is that the Table has a variable number of rows. I can programmatically assign unique IDs to reference the 'implemented cost saving value', the 'unimplemented cost saving value' and the progress bar on each row.

How can I implement this in JQuery so that I don't have to create a new function that explicitly references these IDs, kind of like named parameters in C#?

This is my first time programming in JQuery(is JQuery a javascript library or something?) so excuse my naivety please!

Comment: You can deal with classes instead of ids, and iterate on all your `tr`

Comment: @mguimard could you elaborate? How would I then set different values for each progress bar on each row?

Comment: Sure, see my response below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like that

HTML Markup

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <div class="impl" id="implG13">252,849.00</div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="bar" id="progressBarG13"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="unimpl" id="unimplG13">234,687.00</div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Javascript (With jquery)

```
$("tr").each(function(){
    var $tr = $(this);
    var impl = $tr.find(".impl").val();
    var unimpl = $tr.find(".unimpl").val();
    $tr.find(".bar").progressbar({
        $value : impl/(impl+unimpl)
    });
});
```

Comment: hmmm thanks for the answer but it doesn't seem to be working, I just get lots of progress bars that look like they've all got a val of 1 or something (I've put test data in that should return 99%)

Comment: thought I'd got it, the value formula should be ((impl / (impl + unimpl)) * 100) but this still doesn't seem to work

Comment: $tr.find(".impl").val(); returns an empty string every time, it's not picking up the value

Comment: Thanks again, can you see what's wrong here? ![example](http://s21.postimg.org/cdgxdsyo7/Untitled6.png)

Comment: Seems to be the format of your data (Floats with comma). Use parseFloat( impl.replace(/,/g,'') ); and parseFloat( unimpl.replace(/,/g,'') );

Comment: OK I've got the percentage calculate right but I doesn't seem to be setting the value of the progress bar correctly:  ![example2](http://s16.postimg.org/hlfxyj3yt/Untitled7.png)

Comment: This seems to be an issue related to your layout, try to set a min width to your td which contains the .bar div. Or use a div based layout instead of table ? Cannot really answer actually...

Comment: Got it! I set the progress bar value using the syntax -  "value" : percent

Answer (score 0):

You can use some [more complex selectors in jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/), for example the starts with selector.

```
$('[id^="progressbar"]').each(function() {
    var currentId = $(this).attr('id');
    var index = currentId.replace("progressbar",""); // This removes progressbar from the ID so you get the unique identifier
    var percentage = calculatePercentage(index);
    // Do something with percentage to display it somewhere.
});

function calculatePercentage(index) {
     return ($("#impl"+index).val() / ($("#impl"+index).val() + $("#unimpl"+index).val()));
}
```

You could take a look at [Bootstrap Progress Bars](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/components/#progress) to find some that are relatively easy to implement.

Good luck!